# How to add a new line to a file and match the indentation from prev line

Tags: shell, sed, scripting

I have:

```
globalweather:
    name: 'globalweather:1.0.0'
```

I tried:
`sed -i '' "s/^\( *\)name: '$api_name'$/&\n\1\$ref: $1/" $2`

But i'm getting:

```
globalweather:
    name: 'globalweather:1.0.0'n    $ref: globalweather_1.0.0.yaml
```

I want:

```
globalweather:
   $ref: globalweather_1.0.0.yaml
```

Can someone help me on what I'm missing?

Comment: The `&` in your replacement string gets converted into "the entire matched string".  And then you're adding parts of that string to it. Is that intentional? It doesn't seem to be, based on your intended output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can capture the indention and then use substitution to insert it:

```
sed 's/^\( *\)something$/&\n\1something else/'
```

Breakdown:

```
s/
  ^      # Start of string
  \( *\) # Capture 0 or more spaces
  something
  $      # End of string
/
  &      # Full matched string
  \1     # Captured spaces
  something else
/
```

But there might be a more elegant solution with the `a`fter command.

Comment: I think with `a` it's impossible to change what you're inserting, so your solution is the only one-pass solution I can think of.

Comment: @andlrc Thank you for your reply, I'm actually tring to edit a yaml file by adding another line. Here is what i used based on your suggestion:
`sed -i '' "s/^\( *\)name: '$api_name'$/&\n\1\$ref: $1/" $2`
But i'm getting:

`  
globalweather:
    name: 'globalweather:1.0.0'n    $ref: globalweather_1.0.0.yaml 
`

I want:

`  
globalweather:
   $ref: globalweather_1.0.0.yaml 
`

What did i miss?

Answer (score 0):

@andlrc, thank you for your suggestion, I got it it work, the sed command i used is:

`sed -i '' "s/^\( *\)name: '$api_name'$/\1\$ref: $1/" $2`